# how to make jetpack compose lifecycle compatible with Fragment life cycles?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

My app previous was made using Fragments as pages. Now i'm integrating Jetpack Compose into my app. The pages are like this:

HomePageFragment -> the home page made with traditional XML

ItemListPageFragment -> a fragment wraps ComposeView that everything is done by Compose

ItemDetailPageFragment -> item detail page made with traditional XML

Here are the effects I want to achieve:

- When entering ItemListPage, show loading then a list of items. then user scroll down a bit, select an item, jump to ItemDetailPage
- When go back from ItemDetailPage to ItemListPage, UI shouldn't reload, but stays at where it was left with.

My ItemListPage is like this:

```
@Composable
fun Content(){

   // third party lib that kind of like useSWR for React
   val states = useRequest(fetcher = {....})
   
   if(states.error) {...}
   if(states.loading) {....}

   // render list of items
   ....
}
```

right now it triggers fetch and loading UI when I go back from ItemDetailPage to ItemListPage.

I think the issue is Fragment destroy views when "page-out". Then when it is "back-to" page, it creates new ComposeView and triggered onLoad event.

Comment: So where are you saving the data you've loaded? I would expect loading to happen in a ViewModel (just like you do in a Fragment) or have a small amount of data saved in saved instance state via `rememberSaveable` (just like how you have to save your state in a Fragment).

Comment: "val states = useRequest(fetcher = {....})" this is wrong. You need to do the Google code lab for remembering state in Jetpack Compose.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk that is compounded handle with states and action triggers. it remembers states under the hood

Comment: @ianhanniballake inside useRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-4-pathway-1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#4)

OR

Use [rememberSavable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) so that there won't be change even if there are any configuration changes

Comment: The data is stored in the states, inside "useRequest". it is a composable, i can't put it inside viewmodel